# Does the android mobile application contains "Dalvik" as "User - Agent"

Tags: android, user-agent, mozilla, dalvik, android-runtime

Hi I'm new to **Android** , I m developing native android application to interact with **REST API**.

I would like to **secure** my REST API .i.e, The REST API must only allows the requests from my **native android application** not from **android browser**. So as to achieve the above result I have processed the User Agent string with PHP as backend.

> WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR

- I tried with User Agent string
- I tried with custom user agent string
  ( android application)

  ```
  webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("user-agent-string");
  ```
- I have refered [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) vs [ART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime)

> QUESTION1 :

Is the default user agent string from native android application contains **Dalvik** or **ART** or **Both**

> QUESTION 2:

Why Dalvik was set instead of **Mozilla**

Currently I am getting the following user agent string(tried in 10 different mobile phones)

```
Dalvik/x.x.x (Linux; U; Android x.x.x; <phone model> Build/XXXX
```